# What are the capabilities of React Hot Loader + hot-loader/react-dom as it relates to React Hooks?

Tags: webpack-dev-server, react-hooks, react-hot-loader

I just updated my react configuration to use the new API for `React Hot Loader`. The top-level documentation for `React Hot Loader` (see: [github page](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader)) has me a little confused as to what my expectations should be for this new setup.

There's a section very close to the top entitled **`Hook support`**, and it gets into what the React Hooks support looks like. However, I'm not really following the language used there. For example, does

> ❄️ useState(initialState); // will never updated (preserve state)

imply that any state tracked with `useState` will never be preserved across hot reloads?

In my ideal world, everything handled by Hooks could be tracked across reloads... but I have no idea if that is possible.

Can somebody explain the expected behaviour for React Hooks as they relate to hot reloading (specifically when using these libraries in a way that enables storing the state of React Hooks across reloads)? I recognize that the language currently used in the docs might be clear to some, but it is not to me. :(

Comment: And I should note - I want to know what the expected behaviours are so that I can know whether or not my configuration is running properly. I'm unable to keep `useState` state intact across reloads, and *I have a feeling* that this is the expected behaviour. However - if it is not - I'd like to know that, so that I can get it working properly. :)

Comment: Not a fan of that part of documentation either. Still don't know if it's possible to hot-reload hooks or not.

Comment: Are you using webpack? Because thanks to your post, I've managed to get it to work and now my hooks are being hot-reloaded.

Comment: @cbdev420 are you able to keep `useState` state intact across reloads?